# Ubuntu - Tool for UDP rate-limit

Tags: networking, firewall, deb, debian, sip

I have a SIP gateway machine that I would like to apply some kind of rate limit on the host machine.

Something like - `If an X number of connections happens under Y seconds -> Block source-IP and log it somewhere`

I've tried with UFW but it would drop legitimate calls so I'm looking for something else.

I know IPtables can do the job but I would to invest time in it as a last resort. as it's a lot of time investment.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You've tagged your question being about a Debian/Ubuntu workflow issue, but your question doesn't relate to workflow or packaging*'

Comment: Just change "Deb11" to "Ubuntu 22.04" (or similar). Afterwards I can provide you the hint: https://www.fail2ban.org/

Comment: @Marco Ok, ive changed.

Comment: Oops, I already sent the hint ... :-)

Comment: @Marco Hey, thanks for the advice. but i don't think fail2ban would work at my setup as its performance sensitive so because fail2ban work at the log level and not protocol level it would greatly affect performance in a non-torable way.

I guess ill have to dive iptables after al...